# Why my "search" function only works on some columns of my Boostrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, bootstrap-4

I have set up a js function to let me search in my Boostrap table, but this function only works on two of its columns.

I am a bit of a newbie with Javascript so, even though I can choose what columns to select for the search, I can't select them all. I should also underline that this function is something I used at first in a Boostrap table where I only needed to search some of the columns.

This is my HTML:

```
<section class="main">
    <table id="maintable">
        <thead class="maintable-header">
            <tr>                                           
                <th scope="col" style="width: 5%" class="number"></th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 17.5%" class="role">Role</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 35%" class="project">Project</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 35%" class="credits">Credits</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 7.5%" class="year">Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>



        <tbody id="mainTableBody">

<!-- ########################### ROW 4 ########################### -->
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">4</td>
                <td>Project Management</td>
                <td>Fragile?</td>
                <td>Pentagram Stiftung</td>
                <td>2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo4">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</td>
                <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

<!-- ########################### ROW 5 ########################### -->
            <tr class="rowheader" id="rowheader5">         
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">5</td>
                <td>Project Management</td>
                <td>Fragile?</td>
                <td>Pentagram Stiftung</td>
                <td>2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo5">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.</td>
                <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

<!-- ########################### ROW 6 ########################### -->

            <tr class="rowheader" id="rowheader6">         
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">6</td>
                <td>Curating</td>
                <td>The Book Affair</td>
                <td>Automatic Books</td>
                <td>2009</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo6" style="height: 50px;">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
     </table>
</section>
```

And this is my function:

```
function searchFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("mainTableBody");
  entries = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    a = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    b = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    //console.log(a, b);
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || 
b.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      entries[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      entries[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is the possibility to search all of the columns without excluding any of them.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you please add the full HTML / JavaScript you are using to the question. For example, no where is the `searchFunction` function called, and there is no `#searchInput` field.

Comment: @GaryThomas 100% right, I completely forgot that...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m_tibo/heta8uoq/8/ @GaryThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like to achieve is the possibility to search all of the columns without excluding any of them.

Simply change your search function to search all the `td` elements rather than specifying the two `a` and `b` variables.

Here I make use of the [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and the [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to shorten the code.

```js
function searchFunction() {
    const input = document.getElementById("searchInput"),
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
        table = document.getElementById("mainTableBody"),
        entries = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop all tr elements
    [...entries].forEach(tr => {
        // Loop all td elements, checking if innerHTML contains #searchInput value
        const containsSearch = [...tr.getElementsByTagName("td")].some(td =>
            td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().includes(filter)
        );

        tr.style.display = containsSearch ? "table-row" : "none";
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="searchFunction()" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color ='rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';">

<section class="main">
    <table id="maintable">
        <thead class="maintable-header">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 5%" class="number"></th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 17.5%" class="role">Role</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 35%" class="project">Project</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 35%" class="credits">Credits</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 7.5%" class="year">Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="mainTableBody">
            <tr class="rowheader" id="rowheader5">
                <!-- ########################### ROW 5 ########################### -->
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">5</td>
                <td>Project Management</td>
                <td>Fragile?</td>
                <td>Pentagram Stiftung</td>
                <td>2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo5">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis
                    iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                    accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="rowheader" id="rowheader6">
                <!-- ########################### ROW 6 ########################### -->
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">6</td>
                <td>Curating</td>
                <td>The Book Affair</td>
                <td>Automatic Books</td>
                <td>2009</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo6" style="height: 50px;">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                    elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit id odio minima eos fugiat
                    a aut veniam quasi in, enim quis, iure adipisci ratione, et atque velit distinctio consequuntur nisi!</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="rowheader" id="rowheader7">
                <!-- ########################### ROW 7 ########################### -->
                <td style="padding-left: 0.5%;">7</td>
                <td>Project Management</td>
                <td>Fragile?</td>
                <td>Pentagram Stiftung</td>
                <td>2013</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="projectinfo" id="projectinfo7">
                <td></td>
                <td class="align-text-top">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis
                    iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                    accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Great this actually works! Thanks very much also for the explanation. The only problem is that now it searches also the hidden tr (I have collapsible info for each tr, see pics in the link https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1734469/table.jpg ). Is there a way to exclude those elements?

Comment: Add a class to the hidden `tr` elements, something like `hidden-tr`. Then change `table.getElementsByTagName("tr")` to something like `table.querySelectorAll("tr:not(.hidden-tr)")`.. You really should be adding as much information as possible to your initial question (eg "ignore hidden tr")

Comment: Thanks very much Gary. I know you're right, I should have been more precise. But also since I don't know much yet about javascript, I was trying to not overload the question with useless info. Anyway, thanks again, now if works perfectly!